# Where to buy "Grimbergen" in Canada

Tags: specialty-beers, canada

I've spent much time in Ottawa and Halifax, and have yet to find a consistent source of this nectar of the gods.
Locations Found:

Liquor Store in Whistler, BC

LCBO in Trainyards, Ottawa

Greek Restaurant in Downtown Ottawa

Brussels.

Anyone know where to find it?

Comment: Oooo yeah, Grimbergen Optimo Bruno is the best!!!!

Comment: Needed in QC. Suggestions please...

Comment: In Vancouver, British Columbia I've had it on tap at Bier Craft (biercraft.com)

Comment: I just had Grimbergen Dubbel at Irish Heather on Carral street in Vancouver. Great Pub!

Answer (score 1):

This may not help you in Quebec, but if a product can be found in an LCBO somewhere in Ontario, you should be able to order that product at *any* LCBO in Ontario.

Answer (score 0):

God & Beer partnership gives abbey much needed cash,, they've brought their suds to [Toronto](http://chrisbrooker.ca/index.php/grimbergen-the-beer-so-good-nothing-can-keep-it-from-us/) Lads..

Answer (score 0):

Well there is some small convenient store in Montreal that you can buy some

Here is the address of the one I go:

Dépanneur Paul
50 Avenue des Pins
Montréal, QC H2W 1N5

Answer (score 0):

Toronto - Town Crier Pub (John and Adelaide)

Toronto - Bier Markt (various locations)

Comment: and BeerBistro!

Answer (score 0):

I find it so weird that there is no consistent rules as to why some varieties of beer and ales are so difficult to obtain in Canada. Regulations change even between the provinces. It seems so strange that in BC there is a regular list of products sold in liquor stores as well as a restricted list for restaurants and a specialty list where one can buy products providing one buys the whole box. Some private liquor store may allow you to buy a six-pack if it is permitted to be sold within a particular province. You need to ask and find out if the province carries Grimbergen. One can also order it online using the same criteria. Here is an example for [Alberta.](http://www.liquordirect.ca/Grimbergen-Blonde-P10982.aspx)

If you are fortunate enough to be able to cross the border you will have little trouble finding Grimbergen in the US. Normally would pay duty upon returning to Canada, but in my experience here in BC is that if your bottle of wine is valued less than $10.00 or you are bringing back only a six-pack of beer or cider, you will not pay anything. I always declare my purchases and have yet to pay any duty.